# How Can I make portable xampp project

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, portability

Let I have developed a dictionary application in mysql using php in xampp. That is i can access it using localhost from my browser. But i do not want it to be online. I want to release an offline version of it. So that I can distribute the project using cd or pendrive and user just take it and run it. That is I want to make it portable in offline.

How can I do that. That is should I install xampp in all the cd and import my database ? Or is there any smart solution?

Comment: are u jocking... I belive there is a way.... @Coulton

Comment: And I could do it and most importantly without any laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By it's very nature, XAMPP is portable.  You can just extract it and run it.  When you run it it will run Apache, mySQL and you can access it by `http://localhost` or by a different address according to your host file configuration if it has been changed from the default.

So put it on a laptop or onto a pen drive and you can run your code and database from it.

Here's the description of XAMPP:

> XAMPP is an integrated server package of Apache, mySQL, PHP and Perl (the AMPP in XAMPP) that all run from a removable drive. Everything is pre-configured and ready to go just by unzipping or installing it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to search first? )

There is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12272455/2792335

I think you should first migrate database from MySQL to something like SQLite to avoid need of db server installation.

Then use something like http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm or one of applications referenced in the above mentioned answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and mysql is not a good platform for such task. PHP to operate need running sever(i.e apache) with support for right version of php. an mySQL is commercial product, you can use it for free, but if you want to include it with your product as you described you need commercial license. I would suggest to rewrite product to another platform. In example you can use JavaScript and HTML5 storage instead for data. or pick different database.